# CSS not being updated on PythonAnywhere

Tags: css, pythonanywhere

I am trying to deploy a website on PythonAnywhere.  I was able to get it uploaded and it was working well, then I had some difficulty with git hub.  I think that I have the git hub issue resolved but now the latest css file is not being picked up.

I've tried clearing the cache.  I checked and saw the the CSS file was updated, worked with someone else on trying to resolve it for a bit and when back to the the CSS file and it had reverted to the old one.  I did a new git pull and the file was updated again to the newer version but the CSS is still not getting picked up.

When I look at the Developer Tools a new div class I added is showing up in the HTML but it's not getting pulled from the CSS file.

Can anyone think of something that may be causing the issue?  This feels like a problem with Python Anywhere.

Forgive me if this is a duplicate.  I found a few other posts like this but they all resolved with clearing the cache.  I had more experienced programming looking at my computer and he confirmed that we were clearing it properly.

Answer (score 0):

So I now know what was happening.

Turns out that a second folder named static got set up, this one was capitalized, though and that's where my new files were.
I somehow missed this and would sometimes open up my css file in the static and sometimes in the Static folder which is why I thought it was reverting.